# c# - How to get the static variable of a class

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am developing an app. There are so many dictionaries,lists. In this I want to clear the contents of static dictionaries,lists which are starting with the word "global". Here is the sample code

```
    public static Dictionary<string, TestNo> globalDict = new Dictionary<string, TestNo>();
    public static List<TestNo> globalTestNos= new List<TestNo>(); 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        globalDict.Add("a", 1);
        globalDict.Add("b", 2);
        globalDict.Add("c", 3);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the type of 'MyClass'.
        Type myType = this.GetType();

        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.Static);
        List<string> temp = propertyInfo.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("global")).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
        MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,temp.ToArray()));
    }
```

But it is not working. I am always getting the propertyInfo as empty array. Can anybody guide me on this?

Note: I am using .net3.5. Visual express 2008. This is provided by the company, so I can't change the platform.

Comment: Share ``TestNo`` class and ``myclass`` to clear your question

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad `TestNo` is not required to answer the question. `myclass` is already shown.

Comment: `globalDict` and `globalTestNos` are fields so you should either use `GetFields` or make them properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

should be changed to

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

since `globalTestNos` and `globalDict` are fields (not properties)